# Android - Error: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Tags: android, save, android-external-storage

I'm using [BeagleBuddy](http://www.beaglebuddy.com/content/pages/javadocs/com/beaglebuddy/mp3/MP3.html) mp3 tag editor to make changes to mp3 files on the internal / external storage... Works fine on some phones... but on certain phones, I get this error... (Samsung S4, Note 3) etc...

> **open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)**

I have in my manifest...

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Still no luck... Any suggestions?

I've read a lot about how Android is protecting the external card from edits on some phones... is there a way to get around this?

I've used several different methods to get the external drive... Some work on some phone, some don't work...

This is what I am currently using:

```
public static File getRemovableStorage()
    {
        String value = System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE");
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(value))
        {
            String[] paths = value.split(":");
            for (String path : paths)
            {
                File file = new File(path);
                if (file.isDirectory())
                {
                    return file;
                }
            }
        }
        return null; // Most likely, a removable micro sdcard doesn't exist
    }
```

It finds all of the files on the external drive great... I just get that error when I try to update an mp3 tag on the external drive.

Comment: Are you using `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()`?

Comment: It's better for you to put that on your question...